# Inequality $\frac{4x-9}{3x^2+2} < y$

Tags: functions

I need help with this equation:

$\frac{4x-9}{3x^2+2} < y$

I need to solve for x:

$x < ...$

The best i got so far was:

$x(4-3xy)<2y+9$

Cant find a solution and would be very thankful for a hint.

Comment: Hint: Can you solve $ax^2+bx+c>0$ for $x$?

Comment: Please read this carefully: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question At least the title of your question is far from the guidelines.

Comment: How do i get to $ax2+bx+c>0$?
Couldn't think of a better title. I'll try to make it better next time.

Comment: Is $y$ a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should solve the inequality $$0<3x^2y-4x+9+2y$$ for $x$
now do case work and consider the cases:
$$y=0$$
$$y>0$$
$$y<0$$
and now calculate the discriminant of the equation $$0=3x^2y-4x+9+2y$$

Comment: This is exactly where the OP is stuck.